# how to recover the binary stream(original form) from radix 64 encoding

Tags: python, encoding

how to get the actual public key i.e its binary form i.e without radix 64 conversion .i need to extract the public key from radix64 encoding .the pgp server gives me the key in radix 64 format now i have to extract the public key from it.

Comment: Have exactly same problem, except I'm looking for a java solution....

Answer (score 2):

```
import base64

decoded_bytes = base64.b64decode(ascii_chars)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
base64_encoded_data.decode('base64')
```