# Radix 64 and encryption

Tags: python

Need to share my problem that is :
A PGP public key server gives me the key in Radix64 format .
And i searching for any method which can encrypt my message using this Radix64 format public key .

any alternate suggestions or documents are welcome .........

Answer (score 2):

[exPyCrypto](http://www.freenet.org.nz/ezPyCrypto/) looks good.

This [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387867/how-to-convert-base64-radix64-public-key-to-a-pem-format-in-python) addresses Radix64 format specifically for public keys.

To convert the actual base/radix64 encoded characters, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397799/how-to-recover-the-binary-streamoriginal-form-from-radix-64-encoding):

```
import base64
decoded_bytes = base64.b64decode(ascii_chars)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the key by using the [base64](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html) module and then encrypt the message.